# Moqing HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

I have a unit test that tests an MVC controller's result. Unfortunately the controller uses a third party library that uses `HttpContext.Request.IsLocal`. I cannot refactor the third party library to make it use `HttpContextBase`.

I need to mock this so that `HttpContext.Request.IsLocal` returns true. Any Ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: can't you just mock out the third party library? Not sure would want an external dependency or any dependency in your unit test.

Comment: the problem is that the method is a static method in a static class and hence my only shot at mocking it is by creating a fake HttpContext

Comment: if you are using premium or above version of vs2012, try looking at microsoft.fakes.  it should cater to your situation

Comment: @Slicksim this looks likes it's going to work. however examples on google seem a bit lacking. So if it's not too much to ask, is it possible to see an example? Also if you put this as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer later on

Comment: I don't have an example sorry, i am stuck with professional version, i know from reading that this is what MS intended the Microsoft.Fakes for, to allow this sort of third party testing.  I can work out an example, but it won't be until this evening when i get back to my own desktop with has a better version of vs on it

Comment: @Slicksim :) ... Shims Worked. I have a problem while debugging the test. However if run it (without debugging) the test passes Thanks man, put it as an answer so I'll mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using premium or above version of vs2012, try looking at microsoft.fakes. it should cater to your situation.

Some reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted solution works for you, there are few drawbacks, like dependency on the VS test runner, some problems I read here and there when used with nUnit (or other framework), hard to run these tests with build server like TeamCity, etc.

IMHO the better approach is to isolate the third party lib trough your own shims/wrappers, and not use static methods directly in your code.

Yes, it's a little bit more work, but, it'll be even easier if later you need to upgrade or replace the third party lib - you will be modifying only the wrappers, while your code will not be impacted.